# plural and then verb

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, word-usage

In the contract it says
Thus, the parties agree as follows.
Does this makes sense? In google search it seems i makes sense

But I thought that since parties is a plural, the sentence should be parties agree as follow?

eg. Balls bounce vs ball bounces

Comment: The verb that agrees with the plural _parties_ is _agree_, no problem there. _As follows_ refers to the next part of the text, an could be replaced by _the following_.

Answer (score 2):

"As follows " is used when you are going to give more details about something. It's always singular.

The winners were as follows – Ratha, Pen, Wiliam.